# search multiple order id in same search request on php

Tags: php, mysql, search

hi there i want to search  multiple order id in same search request on my website now my website have only 1 id search and get option like 100  or 101 but i need to search miltiple id search using comma like 100,101,102,103 and get all of those id how can do this here i share my code please help me

```
elseif( $_GET["search_type"] == "order_id" && $_GET["search"] ):
  $search_where = $_GET["search_type"];
  $search_word  = urldecode($_GET["search"]);
  $count        = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN clients ON clients.client_id = orders.client_id WHERE orders.order_id LIKE '%".$search_word."%' && orders.dripfeed='1' && orders.subscriptions_type='1' ");
  $count        -> execute(array());
  $count        = $count->rowCount();
  $search       = "WHERE orders.order_id LIKE '%".$search_word."%'  && orders.dripfeed='1' && orders.subscriptions_type='1' ";
  $search_link  = "?search=".$search_word."&search_type=".$search_where;
```

Comment: What happened to periods in your post? 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LIKE operator you can use IN operator, e.g.`WHERE orders.order_id IN (100,101,102,103)`

**Some important tips:**

- you are using prepared statement and that is good but instead of passing a parameter you use string concatenation: **don't do that** you are exposed to SQL injection, use parameters in prepared statement instead.
- **don't**, i repeat **don't** pass the SQL query condition in the query string: it is worse than the previous problem
- you can get the count of the row directly in a query instead of query all the rows and retrieve the row count (*$count->rowCount()*) for example you can wrap your query like so:

```
$baseQuery = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table";
$countQuery "SELECT count(*) FROM ($baseQuery) AS c";
```

and then excute the $countQuery (*always with prepared statement and parameters*) and get the count immediately